# Sound: Disable automatic input device selection

Tags: sound

If I connect a USB audio device, Ubuntu switches the input device automatically to the newly connected device.
How can I disable this behavior or how can I configure a specific input device permanently?

Answer (score 0):

You can find your input/output sound device with

```
pactl list short sinks
```

Then go to

```
sudo nano /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

And uncomment

```
set-default-sink input
```

And set a default device number you get from pactl

```
set-default-sink input 0
```